# window.print() printing whole page including popup. I only want to print the popup

Tags: printing, popup

I am using

```
<a href="#" target="_blank" onclick="window.print();return false;"><t style="color:#ee8029;">Print</t></a>
```

to print my popup window details. But it is printing the popup window and the background screen as well. I only want the popup window details to be printed.

Any fixes please?

Comment: you should present more of your source code to find a solution faster.

Answer (score 0):

What if you try to use `self` instead `window`?

```
<a href="#" target="_blank" onclick="self.print();return false;">Print</a>
```